# Android Xamarin Not Seeing My Resource.Id.TagName

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a project and am trying to use SetTag on my views. But I need a resource id, so according to internet advices, I have created a tags.xml file in my Resources/values folder, like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <item name="TAG_VIEWPAGER_PAGELAYOUT" type="id"/>
  <item name="TAG_VIEWPAGER_PAGEPOSITION" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Then I try to access it like so after a clean and rebuild, but it doesn't find it. It says TAG_VIEWPAGER_PAGEPOSITION cannot be found.

`view.SetTag(Resource.Id.TAG_VIEWPAGER_PAGEPOSITION, position);`

Help? I am using Android 5.0 Level 21, C# Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

Open the resourcedesigner.cs file [you might want to back it up if you've never done this before]

Click in the file

use CTRL + A to highlight all the code

delete the contents of resourcedesigner.cs completely

clean the solution

rebuild the solution [resourcedesigner.cs should reload automatically]

Sometimes the resource designer file can't keep up with your changes.

If this doesn't work then try searching for TAG_VIEWPAGER_PAGEPOSITION in your resourcedesigner.cs file and let me know if it's in there

Answer (score 0):

It just required a restart for VS, and then everything worked.. so much time trying other solutions.. so agitating...

Comment: in the future doing what I posted below should save you a bit of time.  And yes, this is one annoying thing about Xamarin.Android

Comment: Could you please mark your answer so that others who have similar question could get help from here?